# Recompile of .ts files in Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, typescript, webpack

I got project from another dev its Wordpress theme, he used Typescript which i'm not familliar with, when I change something in .ts file it doesnt change on site, I assume it should be recompiled, but I dont have any folder like node_modules nor package.json so i can't really use npm run build or something like this. Only things that I recognize in theme folder are tailwind.config.js and webpack.config.js + yarn.lock.

How can I edit those .ts files so they acctualy work? Is there any way to install dependencies basing on yarn.lock?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it myself, basically what I did was:

npm init => npm install webpack, then i added script to package.json start: "webpack" and I installed every missing dependency displayed in terminal